# Как задать всем кругам в коллекции другой радиус?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandexmapkit, yandex-geocoding-api

Я добавляю в коллекцию координаты и названия:

```
    TestCollection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, {
        preset: 'islands#rapidTransitIcon',
        }),
        TestCoords = [[55.431397736421026, 37.56551917623395], [55.47047139319212, 37.55547698568209],
        TestName = ['Warum', 'Wo', 'Bist'];
```

потом рисую круги на карте:

```
   const drawCircle = (collection, coords, radius, colour) => {
        let collect = collection;
        let circleColour = colour 
        for (let i = 0, l = coords.length; i < l; i++) {
        collect.add(new ymaps.Circle(
            [coords[i], radius],
            {hintContent: `test`},
            {fillColor: circleColour, fillOpacity: 0.3, strokeColor: circleColour, strokeOpacity: 0.5, strokeWidth: 5}
            ));
        myMap.geoObjects.add(collect);
    }};
```

И потом хочу изменить им радиус на произвольный любой по заданному input. К примеру:

```
document.querySelector('.map_radius').onchange = function () {
        TestCollection.options.setRadius(5);
```

Но код не работает. Что надо сделать, чтобы заработал?

Comment: Выяснил, что на текущий момент так делать нельзя напрямую. Из коллекции удаляем все объекты (круги) и рисуем их заново с заданным параметром.